# I cannot figure out the Formula Syntax Error

Tags: formula-field

I have two formula fields that are not working and the error message is not much help " Error: Syntax error".

I have checked that there are the same amount of open and closed parentheses and also checked the commas are in the correct place.

```
IF(
ISBLANK(End_Time__c),
((NOW() – Start_Time__c)*1440),
((End_Time__c - Start_Time__c )*1440)
)
```

---

IF I remove the `,Owner:Queue.QueueName` then it will work, but I want it to include queue too.

```
If(
BEGINS(OwnerId, “005”),
Owner:User.FirstName &” “& Owner:User.LastName,
Owner:Queue.QueueName
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have "smart quotes".

ie, this is surrounded by smart quotes: `“005”`

Leaving them in causes a "Syntax Error"

I replaced them with regular quotes and your code compiles fine:

```
If(
  BEGINS(OwnerId, "005"),
  Owner:User.FirstName &" "& Owner:User.LastName,
  Owner:Queue.QueueName
)
```

This often happens when you copy paste code from a blog ;)

Comment: Thank you Caspar, soo much. I appreciate it.

Comment: I just tried to remove it and I am still getting an error.
The return is a text
 Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'BEGINS()'. Expected Text, received Number

Comment: By 'remove' I mean, replace with regular quotes. Change `“` to `"` Better still, just copy my entire code block and use it.